# Can't share files of usb connected in router as router's admin page has no option to do it

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, file-sharing

1. When I open my router's admin page, it shows under the `storage devices` category that an external device is connected and also that it is not shared, but there is no option there to share its contents. I looked everywhere, perhaps the provider has locked and hide those features.
   Can someone help me with it?
2. The contents of the usb are available in its(router's) digital media server, but that media server is only accessible through the provider's app on mobile only. There is no app for PC to see it. On my PC, when I open the path of a file from the usb (which I know from the phone app) in my browser, then it begins to download.
   But I don't want to download it. I just want to see all files at one place on PC and read and write them. The path is like `http://ip:2869/.....mkv`.
   I want to see all contents in that place o my PC. I searched `http://ip:2869/` but nothing opened.

Comment: What is the make and model of the router? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: All routers are not created the same. Did you check the manual?